# Error connecting Oracle with Hadoop using Sqoop

Tags: oracle, hadoop, sqoop

I have added ojdbc.jar file in /usr/lib/sqoop/lib and I am trying to connect oracle to hadoop using sqoop but facing error.
 I am using following command:

```
sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:oracle:thin://@192.162.2.8:1521:orcl  --username hr --password abc
```

But the i get following error:

```
15/05/05 09:21:31 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
15/05/05 09:21:32 ERROR manager.OracleManager: Failed to rollback transaction
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.OracleManager.listTables(OracleManager.java:596)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ListTablesTool.run(ListTablesTool.java:49)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:180)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:228)
15/05/05 09:21:32 ERROR manager.OracleManager: Failed to list tables
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:489)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.OracleManager.makeConnection(OracleManager.java:275)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:51)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.OracleManager.listTables(OracleManager.java:585)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ListTablesTool.run(ListTablesTool.java:49)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:180)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:228)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:439)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:454)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:693)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:251)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1140)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:340)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:149)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:133)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:405)
```

is there anyhthing wrong with the sqoop command.?

Answer (score 0):

The error "network adaptor could not establish connection" is coming because of incorrect jdbc url. Jdbc url in your sqoop command should be in this format:  jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.162.2.8:1521:orcl

Comment: thanks for ur response , but its still giving me the same error :(

Comment: Can you please check the host name in oracle net manager. Here are the steps you need to follow:  Go to the oracle net manager then Local -> service naming -> orcl. Then change your HOST NAME and put your PC name. Now go to LISTENER and change the HOST and put your PC name. Save the settings and  restart the oracle server. Then execute your sqoop command

Comment: still not working..
its says connection refused from the host while doing telnet<ip>.
changed the firewall settings too.

Answer (score 0):

The connection refused error may occur by scenarios as far as I know.

- The Oracle service might not be running on the specified host on the
  given port number.
- The firewall in between might restrict the client access to the
  oracle server through the given port number.

So I suggest you to first confirm the oracle host, port and the firewall restriction in between.

you can easily check the access by using telnet as below,

```
 telnet 192.162.2.8 1521
```

Comment: So, it means the problem could be due to either of the above 2 reasons...pls confirm them..

Comment: but if i use telnet 192.162.2.8.. then too it gives the same error ..
without providing the port no. .It still gives Connection Refused.

Comment: Now the oracle server is reachable, u can check with ping...but the firewall might be there in between n blocking the port access I guess...

Comment: telnet <ip> gives connection refused :(

Answer (score 0):

See if the listener and the database are initiated. I just started the listener (lsnrctl start) and the database (sqlplus / as sysdba    and     startup) and it worked.